# How to correlate these values in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to correlate the subjetcs which are highlighted in blue boxes in the below image. When I tried corellating, The values which are highlighted in black color boxes were also captured. I want to capture only those values randomly (highlighted in blue color boxes) which are under combination dropdown (highlighted in yellow color).Please help

[image: Response data]

Answer (score 0):

1. To extract the values starting with `A`  from `search_comb` dropdown you can use [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) configured like:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `value`
   - XPath query: `//select[@name='search_comb']/option[starts-with(@value,'A')]/@value`

     [image]

     Demo:

     [image]
2. To refer random value later on you can use [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination like:

   ${__V(value_${__Random(1,${value_matchNr},)},)}

   [image]

Comment: Thank you it helped me!!!. But what if I want to capture the values starting with A and B also?

Comment: `//select[@name='search_comb']/option/@value` will select all options of the `search_comb` dropdown